# Iterate across SQL Server table, redistributing values between columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to map drug coverage across a 3 year period using purchase data.  Coverage is considered having at least one dose available per month. Example: I buy 6 doses of drug A in month 6.  I will be considered covered for months 6 through 11.

I have constructed a base table with the following fields and example values

```
PatientID  PurchaseMonth  Doses DrugType    Month1  Month2  Month3 ... Month36 
1234       1              2     NSAID       1       1       0          0
1234       1              1     NSAID       0       1       0          0
```

This was then rolled up to get a view of DrugType coverage for each patient

```
Patient  DrugType  Month1  Month2  Month3 ... Month36
1234     NSAID     1       2       0          0
```

Since a given patient only needs 1 dose/month, but is free to use extra doses at any point in the future, **I would like to redistribute any value over 1 to the next available 'empty' month.**  Essentially iterating through each month column and taking any dose over 1 and distributing that value over future months with 0 doses (can't distribute backwards, say month2 -> month1).

**Expected Result:**

```
Patient  DrugType  Month1  Month2  Month3 ... Month36
1234     NSAID     1       1       1          0
```

If no empty months exist I would like to add the residual doses to a holding column, let's call that the 'bank'.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to tackle this with SQL.  I am running this on SQL Server.  I've looked at While and If/Then clauses, but don't see how to apply them to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to fix this at the point of `INSERT`, so that you never add a dose to a month that already has one.  If you don't own or can't control the application that is doing the `INSERTs`, you could use a `TRIGGER`.

If that's not an option, I would look into changing your roll-up code so that you `SUM` the doses for a `PatientID` & `DrugType`, and then starting with the `PurchaseMonth`, add 1 to each column after it, ignoring the month column in the original table.   It might be easier to do this if you `UNPIVOT` the data, create rows, and then `PIVOT`.